# How to add friends to specific list on facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am searching for a way to select all friends that attended to an event, and add them to a specific list.

This should have been implemented in facebook already, as they are blocking profiles for doing massive event invites, without providing tools for massively organize these friends per categories. There should be a way to select all the friends that joined an event, add them to a list, and invite this list for events that will interest the list.

This JS code helps to massive invite all friends. Does anybody know how to modify this in order to add these selected profiles to a list? I have searched the API and didnt find anything that could work so far.

```
javascript:elms=document.getElementsByName(“checkableitems[]“);for (i=0;i<elms.length;i++){if (elms[i].type=”checkbox” )elms[i].click()};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i do not know the facebook api very well and when i used it in 2009 was surprised by the lack of docs and the forum was quite useless. but if they have a way to add a person to list via php code why not do that? just have to do it in a loop?

Comment: os javascript if they have a function to add one person to one list?

Comment: which would be that function? I cannot find the right documentation anywhere. thanks!

Comment: this did not help -> https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+api+add+friend+list ?